# Performance degrades a lot by using mpirun to execute my program

Tags: mpi, intel, distributed-computing, openmpi

I am new to the field of MPI. I write my program by using Intel Math Kernel Library and I want to compute a matrix-matrix multiplication by blocks, which means that I split the large matrix X into many small matrixs along the column as the following. My matrix is large, so each time I only compute (N, M) x (M, N) where I can set M manually.

```
XX^T = X_1X_1^T + X_2X_2^T + ... + X_nX_n^T
```

I first set the number of total threads as 16 and M equals to 1024. Then I run my program directly as the following . I check my cpu state and I find that the cpu usage is 1600%, which is normal.

```
./MMNET_MPI --block 1024 --numThreads 16
```

However, I tried to run my program by using MPI as the following. Then I find that cpu usage is only 200-300%. Strangely, I change the block number to 64 and I can get a little performance improvement to cpu usage 1200%.

```
mpirun -n 1 --bind-to none ./MMNET_MPI --block 1024 --numThreads 16
```

I do not know what the problem is. It seems that `mpirun` does some default setting which has an impact on my program. The following is a part of my matrix multiplication code. The command `#pragma omp parallel for` aims to extract the small N by M matrix from compression format parallel. After that I use `clubs_dgemv` to compute the matrix-matrix multiplication.

```
#include "MemoryUtils.h"
#include "Timer.h"
#include "omp.h"
#include <mpi.h>
#include <mkl.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  omp_set_num_threads(16);
  Timer timer;
  double start_time = timer.get_time();

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  int total_process;
  int id;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &total_process);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

  if (id == 0) {
    cout << "========== Testing MPI properties for MMNET ==========" << endl;
  }

  cout << "Initialize the random matrix ..." << endl;

  unsigned long N = 30000;
  unsigned long M = 500000;
  unsigned long snpsPerBlock = 1024;

  auto* matrix = ALIGN_ALLOCATE_DOUBLES(N*M);
  auto* vector = ALIGN_ALLOCATE_DOUBLES(N);
  auto* result = ALIGN_ALLOCATE_DOUBLES(M);
  auto *temp1 = ALIGN_ALLOCATE_DOUBLES(snpsPerBlock);
  memset(result, 0, sizeof(double) * M);

  cout << "Time for allocating is " << timer.update_time() << " sec" << endl;

  memset(matrix, 1.1234, sizeof(double) * N * M);
  memset(vector, 1.5678, sizeof(double) * N);
  // #pragma omp parallel for
  // for (unsigned long row = 0; row < N * M; row++) {
  //     matrix[row] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
  // }

  // #pragma omp parallel for
  // for (unsigned long row = 0; row < N; row++) {
  //     vector[row] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
  // }

  cout << "Time for generating data is " << timer.update_time() << " sec" << endl;

  cout << "Starting calculating..." << endl;

  for (unsigned long m0 = 0; m0 < M; m0 += snpsPerBlock) {
    uint64 snpsPerBLockCrop = std::min(M, m0 + snpsPerBlock) - m0;
    auto* snpBlock = matrix + m0 * N;

    MKL_INT row = N;
    MKL_INT col = snpsPerBLockCrop;
    double alpha = 1.0;
    MKL_INT lda = N;
    MKL_INT incx = 1;
    double beta = 0.0;
    MKL_INT incy = 1;
    cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor, CblasTrans, row, col, alpha, snpBlock, lda, vector, incx, beta, temp1, incy);

    // compute XA
    double beta1 = 1.0;
    cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor, CblasNoTrans, row, col, alpha, snpBlock, lda, temp1, incx, beta1, result, incy);
  }

  cout << "Time for computation is " << timer.update_time() << " sec" << endl;
  ALIGN_FREE(matrix);
  ALIGN_FREE(vector);
  ALIGN_FREE(result);
  ALIGN_FREE(temp1);
  return 0;
}
```

My cpu information is as the following.

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              44
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-43
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  22
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6152 CPU @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             1252.786
CPU max MHz:         2101.0000
CPU min MHz:         1000.0000
BogoMIPS:            4200.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            30976K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-21
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   22-43
```

Comment: There is no MPI in your code

Comment: Does running `mpirun ... perf stat ./MMNET_MPI` shed any light on anything?  `--bind-to none` should be the same as running it normally, but perhaps it is actually setting CPU affinity somehow?  Maybe run `taskset -p $(pidof MMNET_MPI)` while your job is running to query the affinity mask see if mpirun did set something other than all-ones (`ffff` or whatever).  Or if it started multiple copies of your program?  Or maybe it passes OpenMP env vars?  (What OS are you using?  Linux?)

Comment: It will help if you provide information on which MPI implementation is that (Open MPI?), which version, how do you transform that `--numThreads` argument into MKL threads count, how do you link your executable with MKL, and so on.

Comment: @ptb This is only a small part of my program. I only run this program with one process. So I believe that it does not matter.

Comment: @HristoIliev I use the Open MPI version of 2.1.1 which is a little bit older version. I use the command `omp_set_num_threads` to set the number of threads used in my program. I link the MKL library according to the instruction from official website.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am checking the stat of my MPI program. My OS is Linux. At first, I believe that there is something wrong with CPU affinity. However, I can parallel the for loop normally without the Intel MKL API. This is what I am confused.

Comment: Perhaps MKL looks at an environment variable?  `mpirun -n 1 --bind-to none env` shows what env vars it sets.  I don't see anything obvious that would affect OpenMP.

Comment: @PeterCordes OMPI_MCA_mpi_yield_when_idle=0
OMPI_MCA_orte_app_num=0
OMPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE=1
OMPI_MCA_orte_num_nodes=1
OMPI_MCA_shmem_RUNTIME_QUERY_hint=mmap
OMPI_MCA_orte_bound_at_launch=1
OMPI_MCA_ess=pmi
OMPI_MCA_orte_ess_num_procs=1
OMPI_COMM_WORLD_SIZE=1
OMPI_COMM_WORLD_LOCAL_SIZE=1
OMPI_MCA_orte_tmpdir_base=/tmp
OMPI_NUM_APP_CTX=1
OMPI_FIRST_RANKS=0
OMPI_APP_CTX_NUM_PROCS=1

Comment: Yeah exactly, just OMPI vars, not anything you'd expect to limit OpenMP number of threads, or MKL.  So we can probably reject that hypothesis.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just find an interesting thing. When I call `mkl_set_num_threads()`, the program can fully use the cpu resource normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MKL by default implements some intelligent dynamic selection of the number of threads to use. This is controlled by the variable `MKL_DYNAMIC`, which is set to `TRUE` by default. The documentation for MKL states:

> If you *[sic]* are able to detect the presence of MPI, but cannot determine if it has been called in a thread-safe mode (it is impossible to detect this with MPICH 1.2.x, for instance), and `MKL_DYNAMIC` has not been changed from its default value of `TRUE`, Intel MKL will run one thread.

Since you call `MPI_Init()` and not `MPI_Init_thread()` to initialise MPI, you are effectively asking for single-threaded MPI level (`MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`). The library is free to provide you any threading level and it will conservatively stick to `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`. You can check that by calling `MPI_Query_thread(&provided)` after the initialisation and see if the output value is greater than `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`.

Since you are mixing OpenMP and threaded MKL with MPI, you should really tell MPI to initialise at a higher threading support level by calling `MPI_Init_thread()`:

```
int provided;

MPI_Init_thread(NULL, NULL, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);
// This ensures that MPI actually provides MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE
if (provided < MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE) {
  // Complain
}
```

(technically, you need `MPI_THREAD_FUNNNELED`, if you do not make MPI calls from outside the main thread, but that is not thread-safe mode as MKL understands it)

Even if you request certain thread support level from MPI, there is no guarantee that you will get it, which is why you have to examine the provided level. Also, older Open MPI versions must explicitly be build with such support - the default is to not build with support for `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` as some network modules are not thread-safe. You can check if that's the case by running `ompi_info` and looking for a line similar to this one:

```
Thread support: posix (MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: yes, OPAL support: yes, OMPI progress: no, ORTE progress: yes, Event lib: yes)
```

Now, the reality is that most threaded software that does not make MPI calls outside the main thread runs perfectly fine even if MPI does not provide higher level of thread support than `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE`, i.e., with most MPI implementations `MPI_THREAD_SINGLE` is equivalent to `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`. In that case, setting `MKL_DYNAMIC` to `FALSE` should make MKL behave as when run without `mpirun`:

```
mpirun -x MKL_DYNAMIC=FALSE ...
```

In any case, since your program accepts the number of threads as an argument, simply call both `mkl_set_num_threads()` and `omp_set_num_threads()` and do not rely on magical default mechanisms.

Edit: Enabling full thread support has consequences - increased latency and some network modules may refuse to work, for example the InfiniBand module in older Open MPI versions, resulting in the library quietly switching to slower transports such as TCP/IP. Better request `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED` and explicitly set the number of MKL and OpenMP threads.